# node.js says it can't find sqlite3 module

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I am using to create a todo-app backend using Sqlite3 and Node.js express framework. When I enter `yarn start` or `npm start` it gives an error as follows,I cannot understand what should I do for this error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883

throw err;

^

Error: Cannot find module './modules/sqlite3'

Require stack:

- /home/user/todo-app/server/routes/index.js

- /home/user/todo-app/server/app.js

- /home/user/todo-app/server/bin/www
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)


at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)

at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)

at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/todo-app/server/routes/index.js:5:14)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)

at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)

 

{
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/user/todo-app/server/routes/index.js',
    '/home/user/todo-app/server/app.js',
    '/home/user/todo-app/server/bin/www'
  ]
}
```

Can someone give a solution for this error?

Comment: Have you installed the Sqlite?

Answer (score 1):

You might not have it installed.

```sh
$ npm i sqlite3
```

Comment: i have installed it but didn't work, return the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command from your terminal:

```
$ npm install
```

Comment: can you please share your bin/ww and app.js files? and also the OS/Machine you are using(not very specific but like mac or windows system)?

Comment: https://github.com/Anjula1996/todo-app-backend   only contain www file and app.js file and i am using linux OS

Comment: I needed to see your package.json file aswell. could you just push the project to the repo? would  be  more  helpful

Comment: yes sure here is the link of project repo https://github.com/Anjula1996/todo-app-backend

Answer (score -3):

Its simple. Move your project folder into the desktop and then try again it will work. That's all